# SQL query optimize

Tags: sql, query-optimization

In a slide http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/models-for-hierarchical-data, i saw a sql code (page 22):

```
INSERT INTO Comments (author, comment)
VALUES (‘Ollie’, ‘Good job!’);

SELECT path FROM Comments
WHERE comment_id = 7;

UPDATE Comments
SET path = $parent_path || LAST_INSERT_ID() || ‘/’
WHERE comment_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

I think we can optimize it:

```
SELECT path FROM Comments
WHERE comment_id = 7;

INSERT INTO Comments (author, comment, path )
VALUES (‘Ollie’, ‘Good job!’,  $parent_path || LAST_INSERT_ID() || ‘/’);
```

Am I right?

Comment: What would be the value of LAST_INSERT_ID() in your insert?

Comment: I think the id from the insert-statement. Have look at the slide.

Comment: But there was no previous insert statement in the optimized statements, only a select statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a single insert would be better than an insert followed by an update, but in this case the auto-generated id(?) is being used as a column value as well. The LAST_INSERT_ID() used in the path would not be the id of the current insert statement being performed, but that of the last (previous) insert.

Comment: Is there any sql-function INSERT_ID_OF_THIS_INSERT()?

Comment: Well, it is a bit unusual to be using the id as part of another column value. What would be more typical is to capture the returned id and use it for inserting child records (ex insert an order, use the returned order_id for inserts into the order_details table). Or create a stored procedure to handle this kind of stuff.

Comment: +1 to Glenn, it's true that you have to do the INSERT first, and then form the path, if you use LAST_INSERT_ID().  There is no INSERT_ID_OF_THIS_INSERT() function in MySQL.  You can't even write a trigger to edit the path column, because the new id is not generated until the *after* trigger, when it's too late to modify column contents.  (PS: I'm the author of the slide deck the OP links to.)